# How to create utility type which will extract leaves of a recursive type with path attribute accumulation

Tags: typescript

Let's say we have `Router` recursive type, where each router contains list of endpoints and a list of nested routers. All routers and endpoints are identified by `path`.

```js
type Router = {
  path: '/first';
  endpoints: [
    { path: '/'; schema: { a: number } },
    { path: '/test'; schema: { b: number } }
  ];
  routers: [
    {
      path: '/second';
      endpoints: [
        { path: '/'; schema: { c: number } },
        { path: '/test'; schema: { d: number } }
      ];
      routers: [
        {
          path: '/third';
          endpoints: [
            { path: '/test'; schema: { e: number } }
          ];
        },
      ];
    },
  ];
};
```

How to create utility type `ExtractEndpoints` which will be used like this:

```js
type EndpointMap = ExtractEndpoints<Router>;
```

and produce type like this:

```js
type EndpointMap = {
  '/first': { a: number };
  '/first/test': { b: number };
  '/first/second': { c: number };
  '/first/second/test': { d: number };
  '/first/second/third/test': { e: number };
};
```

Here is link to the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBASg9gV2BATlAvFA3gKClMAQ2AAsAuKAcgHoAzASxQGdhKBuPKCAOwBMw49bsCYUA2p3xYCxclWrsoTAMYkIAW0IVpWqNwTqARqigBfMwBpJ2GaQo1kLRSrWbtUQxX1GT505wBdDnwURGRmcWtcfBjbORomCGU4PnZrfB5+QWFRKAlY2OkiO3lnVQ1daWUvA2M0PysCmKLZe2pHVjYlcrcbXhqferN0qCCR0KRUXPym7BHY4vj2kkZeNNmYzIEhEUiNwri2jrLXSq4BurNh-dHg2dNGgrHYh8COUw4cam+oUEgoACiAA9gChCMpgAC+NscgAeAAqAD4MFAAHTor4-P7QKFZHYAWUIYBRwNB4Mh0OyIlh8EmKEROBw2MBlIJRJR0XkDGYrHcum8lw+nBo3JY7QgTncnj0tV8dxFjDFiWSqXc1RlgzM8roiuA1GVKV44slfQucuFOp5+qShuWq2NvJsEDN9XebCAA).

Comment: These deeply recursive types invariably have bizarre edge cases, so please test [this potential solution](https://tsplay.dev/WP8eZW) thoroughly.  If it meets your needs, let me know and I'll write up an answer explaining.  If it doesn't, please [edit] the example code in the question to show the unsatisfied use case.

Comment: The solution you provider works as expected, wow. Haven't found any edge cases yet. I was worried about performance, but tested on 1200 lines of this recursive type and response is isntant so it should good enough. Big thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an initial caveat: in my experience, deeply recursive utility types often have strange edge case behavior which can be difficult to modify without completely refactoring.  Depending on how you want `ExtractEndpoints<T>` in the face of some subproperties of `T` being [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) or [optional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties) or having [index signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures), the solution I present here might not be appropriate. Generally speaking one should thoroughly test any such utility type against expected use cases before using it in your code base.

---

First we can define some helper interfaces to describe the shapes of acceptable type arguments to `ExtractEndpoints<T>`:

```
interface Endpoint {
  path: string;
  schema: any;
}

interface BaseRouter {
  path: string;
  endpoints?: readonly Endpoint[];
  routers?: readonly BaseRouter[]
}

type ExtractEndpoints<T extends BaseRouter> = ⋯;
```

Hopefully that makes sense.  Now we need to define `ExtractEndpoints<T>`.

---

My approach will be to make an intermediate helper type with a name like `_EE<T>` which produces the entries of `ExtractEndpoints<T>` as a union of key-value [tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types).  So in your example, `_EE<Router>` should look like `["/first", {a: number}] | ["/first/test", {b: number}] | ⋯`.  Given that type we can easily write `ExtractEndpoints` as a [mapped type with remapped keys](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as):

```
type ExtractEndpoints<T extends BaseRouter> = 
  { [E in _EE<T> as E[0]]: E[1] };
```

Now we need to define `_EE<T>`:

---

This will have to be a [recursive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#recursive-conditional-types).  It will need to compute both the union of key-value tuples corresponding to the current router's `endpoints` property; and, recursively, the union of key-value tuples corresponding to the routers in its `routers` property.  In anticipation of that recursion, we will also give `_EE<T>` a second type parameter `P`, corresponding to the current path prefix.  So `_EE<T, P>` will prepend `P` to all the paths.  And the default behavior of `_EE<T>` will be to supply the empty string [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) `""` for `P`.

Let's look at each piece separately:

---

Given a `T` assignable to `BaseRouter`, its own key-value union from `endpoints` looks like:

```
T['endpoints'] extends readonly (infer E)[] ? E extends Endpoint ?
   [`${P}${T['path']}${SlashToEmpty<E['path']>}`, E['schema']] 
: never : never
```

That uses [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) to extract the element types of the `endpoints` array as `E`, and a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) so that any unions in `E` are broken into individual members, processed separately, and then the result re-joined into a new union.

The key, `` `${P}${T['path']}${SlashToEmpty<E['path']>}` `` is a [template literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) that concatenates the prefix `P`, the current router `T`'s `path` property, and the endpoint `E`'s `path` property.  Well, except I have `SlashToEmpty` in there, which I haven't defined.  That looks like

```
type SlashToEmpty<T extends string> = T extends "/" ? "" : T;
```

And this is because for some reason your `path` properties are set to `"/"` when you actually don't want to append anything at all to the path.  Not sure what the deal is there; it would have been more straightforward for the path to be the empty string literal `""` instead of `"/"`.  But whatever, we can just use `SlashToEmpty<T>` to evaluate to `T` for all `T` except `"/"`.

---

And given `T` assignable to `BaseRouter`, the union of key-value tuples from the `router` property looks like

```
T['routers'] extends readonly (infer R)[] ? 
  _EE<R, `${P}${T['path']}`> : 
never
```

We're pulling out the routers from `T['routers']` into `R`, and then recursively computing `_EE<R, ⋯>` with a new path prefix that comes from concatenating the current prefix `P` with the current path `T['path']`.  We also want this to distribute over unions, so one way to do that is to make the entire `_EE<T, P>` a distributive conditional type in `T`.

---

Let's put that all together:

```
type ExtractEndpoints<T extends BaseRouter> = 
  { [E in _EE<T> as E[0]]: E[1] };

type SlashToEmpty<T extends string> = T extends "/" ? "" : T;

type _EE<T, P extends string = ""> = T extends BaseRouter ?
  (T['endpoints'] extends readonly (infer E)[] ? E extends Endpoint ?
    [`${P}${T['path']}${SlashToEmpty<E['path']>}`, E['schema']] : never : never) |
  (T['routers'] extends readonly (infer R)[] ? _EE<R, `${P}${T['path']}`> : never)
  : never
```

It's not pretty, but it works, at least for the example code from the question:

```
type EndpointMap = ExtractEndpoints<Router>;
/* type EndpointMap = {
    "/first": { a: number; };
    "/first/test": { b: number; };
    "/first/second": { c: number; };
    "/first/second/test": { d: number; };
    "/first/second/third/test": { e: number; };
} */
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBASg9gV2BATlAvFA3gKClMAQ2AAsAuKAcgHoAzASxQGdhKBuPKCAOwBMw49bsCYUA2p3xYCxclWrsoTAMYkIAW0IVpWqNwTqARqigBfMwBpJ2GaQo1kLRSrWbtUQxX1GT505wBdDnwURGRmcWtcfBjbORomCGU4PnZrfB5+QWFRKAlY2OkiO3lnVQ1daWUvA2M0PysCmKLZe2pHVjYlcrcbXhqferN0qCCR0KRUXPym7BHY4vj2kkZeNNmYzIEhEUiNwri2jrLXSq4BurNh-dHg2dNGgrHYh8COUw4cHdRaQmVoACifG2wjm+EWFBYKCEAHM7i4KhRCNwQO8vsIfn9oAAhQiJeCTNDRQ5KYDQ7hwzhbbIiAD8FBQEEIvBSABsQFAgVkdmJnlAJuEmPT+UyWdx2VBcfiwqheTh-DhQJAoABlVl4kgAFTgAPUYFAAB5NVwAB7IPhMUnkmEAPgwUGNEDNmUtACJqK6oLSoK7PRRNZ8ldAAPoAgFGixQAAKpvNvEtUNh9t9dswjudFsleIgBPCXs4AApNWJKNSdkxKAFYy6Rcy2RyC0JaCYAQBKXleznVzNckHAfOxMQAAwAJFgo6Yx8XKItK5OsGqNdrdfqQAaASXZwEbaYh5GN5QEZpK1WvBAAG4mM+XlCtqAAH0L04FU0r3fjtbFEsb3GbaBg7ZVt6obhjAkajuO87Tluu52teqCtpw8EoDgirgICZooH8wC9jSTBGu+lpSjmMooKmNhiACUBCFAIFGnaeKcmIAAMAQBBQG4AIxVgqQacsCNIALKEGA9oAph2G4eWBq5qgNocNQABUUB8VJwjCaJmDEvg7oMMwwCuto8xQLo3h1Hc+AfNYumMCw7QQCwhlgrMnh6LUqAWWYnk2fp1CJMkfBOdpBTVG5gyeVZsQ+XZ-kpLw9mOUZGz9GF5nWJFMTRcAflJHFyyrAlBlJbMEAXB56XvFAinUDgQA)